# Applying a weight matrix to an existing graph

Tags: r, igraph

Suppose I have a very simple undirected graph `G` with *n*=4 nodes:

```
G = graph_from_literal(1--2, 1:2--3, 1--4)
```

and a *n*x*n* weight matrix `W` such as:

```
    1   2   3   4
1 0.0 0.5 0.9 1.3
2 0.5 0.0 1.0 0.0
3 0.9 1.0 0.0 0.0
4 1.3 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

**Question: What is the fastest way of applying weights in `W` to the edges of `G`?**

I could use the `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` function like the following:

```
G1 = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(ECV, mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE, diag=FALSE)
```

and then map the `weight`attribute of G1 to edges in G. 
But it is a very expensive (and not elegant) solution when `G` is a very big graph.

How can this be done?

Comment: There is no edge in between the vertices `2` to `4`, but `W[2,4]=1.4`, also the graph is un-directed but `W` is not symmetric, how come?

Comment: Maybe a reshape and merge approach like `E(G)$weight <- merge(get.edgelist(G),reshape2::melt(W),by=1:2)$value;plot(G, edge.label = E(G)$weight)`? Although `merge` tends to be slowish. And prly not more efficient. hmm

Comment: @SandipanDey assume W is given for vertex-pairs and I just want to assign to vertex-pairs who actually are connected by edges.

Comment: `1-4` is connected but `W[1,4]=1.3` whereas `W[4,1]=0.4`, which weight to choose?

Comment: @SandipanDey fixed.

Comment: @grd Something like this should work, if I understood you correctly: `G=graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(W)*as.matrix(get.adjacency(G, type="both")), mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)`
`

Comment: @grd added an answer, please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work:

```
library(igraph)
G = graph_from_literal(1--2, 1:2--3, 1--4)

# The weighted adjacency matrix of the new graph should be obtained simply 
# by element-wise multiplication of W with the binary adjacency of G

G=graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(W) * 
             as.matrix(get.adjacency(G, type="both")), mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)
plot(G, edge.label=E(G)$weight)
```

**[Edit]**

As per the quick fixes discussed in the comments, if the weight matrix contains zeros and we don't want deletion of the corresponding edges, we can set the edge values to a small number:
`W[ which(W == 0) ] = .Machine$double.xmin`.

Now, in order to show the value of the weight in the graph plot correctly, before plotting the graph we can update the edge weights, without affecting the adjacency matrix, as follows:

`E(graph)[ which(E(graph)$weight == .Machine$double.xmin) ]$weight = 0.0`

[image]

Comment: Problem:  if the computed weight is 0.0, he will delete the edge which I don't want to.

Comment: @grd: quick fix: we can filter and modify 0 weights by some very small weight, e.g., `W[W==0.0,] <- 0.0001`

Comment: Yes, like this:  `W[ which(W == 0) ] = .Machine$double.xmin` .

Comment: There is another quick fix to do:  after re-creating the graph we are left with a bunch of edges having weight equals to `.Machine$double.xmin` which should actually re-set to 0.

It can be done with:
`E(graph)[ which(E(graph)$weight == .Machine$double.xmin) ]$weight = 0.0` .

If you edit your response for the fixes I will mark it as correct. Otherwise I will post a solution by myself.

Comment: Updated the post @grd